# Not able to increase Quota for Compute Engine API in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to increase Quota for Google Cloud Platform(GCP) Compute Engine API for a Location and it is not allowing me to Edit or Even select the location.

[image]

I have tried the same thing before few months back and it was properly working then. I just created a new project and tried the same thing.

I do have the **Owner Permission** assigned to me.

Comment: Are you inside free trial?

Comment: yes, few months back in free trial it was allowing to change quota

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After concluding that you are in Free Tier, that is part of constraints.

Your free trial credit applies to all Google Cloud resources, with the following exceptions:

- You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time.
- You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.
- **You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see Resource quotas.**
- You can't create VM instances that are based on Windows Server images.
- **You must upgrade your account to perform any of the actions in the preceding list.**

Upgrading to a paid account:
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade

Free Tier conditions:
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

Update: To be able to increase Quotas or Submit Quota Increase, you need to:

- For New Project need to wait for 48hrs
- You need to have Billing Enabled (Enable it by going into top-left gift icon and following along to Enable Billing in GCP)

Comment: But is there some changes recently, because this is something i was able to perform last year around Nov.

Comment: I wasn’t aware of this eather until I started using more than 20 machines, maybe it gets disabled when you use some of more general quotas. I.e. total number of machines disables number of machines in concrete region if general is filled up.

Comment: Do you have other projects running in that account?

Comment: I am able to perform the action now to select the Quota, i clicked on the top right gift icons and upgraded the billing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I’m glad it helped, just be careful now since you can spend a lot of money if you don’t pay attention to billing section of the console.

Comment: Don’t forget to accept answers if they helped you. That helps other people to know that solution worked. Not just for my answer, but in general it’s nice behavior in Stackoverflow community. Have a nice day! :D